# Laplacian using SDP 

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization, eigenvalues

Is there any suggestion about how could one construct a model that uses semidefinite programming that minimizes sum of k smallest eigenvalues of Laplacian matrix?
I found two papers that have done something for the just bound not for optimization.

Comment: minimizing sum of $k$-largest is a convex problem; the sum of $k$-smallest eigenvalues is concave, and therefore, not really that conducive to minimization...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. i tried another way using the maximization of k-largest eigenvalues.